# Lambda Regex Recognition

Tags: python, lambda

I'm reading an XLS list and run a for loop on a column called 'Product Name'. I want to check line by whether the string matches a certain pattern or not using regex. If the string matches the pattern I want to write it into an array.
This is my for loop to process line by line the product names:

```
    products = []
    for x in df['Product Name']:
        products.append(lambda x : labeler(x))
    print(products)code
```

and this is the function I'm calling:

```
def labeler(product):
    recognized_pattern = re.search(r"abc\w+(\s)?\w+(.|\s)?\w+", product, re.IGNORECASE)
    return recognized_pattern
```

when I print the products array I'm getting millions of strings like this:

**<function main.. at 0x000001C9208D41F0>**

how can I write the recognized pattern into the products array?

Comment: `products = [labeler(x) for x in df['Product Name']]`. Same result, but makes the intent clearer, as anything could be in the body of the `for` loop, but the list comprehension can *only* define a new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lambda` returns an anonymous function, you just want to evaluate your function to get the result so you should write:

```
products.append(labeler(x))
```

Note that when you write this

```
for x in df['Product Name']:
    products.append(lambda x : labeler(x))
```

You might think that `labeler(x)` is being passed the `x` from your dataframe. But it is not. You wrote `lambda x` which, in the scope of your append, means that the `x` from the dataframe is being shadowed by the `x` from the lambda.